# Storing logs of multiple users in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a scenario with over 10K users and, for each user, I need to store an activity log.

The log needs to be searchable and permanent (no wrap around buffer, etc).

I am expecting to have a maximum of 50K entries per user.

I am wondering if it makes sense to store the log entries as a collection inside a user object

```
{
  User : "my user",
  Log : [ ..., ..., ...]
}
```

Or have a table per user?

```
{
  User : "my user",
  LogTableID : "my table id"
}
```

and each entry in that table would be the log.

Comment: won't a search like getting logs from a specific user and doing pagination be slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, neither makes sense. Create just one collection that stores logs for all users.

If you index it by `user_id` (as you should), lookups by user will be fast. **And** you'll be able to do aggregate queries across users (you never know when you'll need to make that report).

Comment: The collection will grow up to 500M entries, that's not going to be a problem to store the index? I should have mentioned that reviewing the logs is a common operation done done a few times daily by the users themselves, so most of the operations on this DB will be users browsing their logs.

Comment: @Thomas: if you have enough ram to support your working set, you won't have any problems with the single collection. If you don't have enough ram, you'll have problems regardless of approach you choose.